# Installing new package is crashing my project

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to add bcryptjs in my application and it's successfully installed but on starting the dev environment, it crashes. Note that the project is currently running on angular v6 and on npm install, it install it's packages and then crashes on dev environment after running ng serve. I can only run the project using old node modules.
My package.json file:

```
{
"name": "@coreui/coreui-free-angular-admin-template",
"version": "2.0.0-beta.5",
"description": "CoreUI Free Angular 2+ Admin Template",
"author": {
"name": "Łukasz Holeczek",
"url": "http://holeczek.pl",
"github": "https://github.com/mrholek",
"twitter": "https://twitter.com/lukaszholeczek"
},
"contributors": [
{
  "name": "Andrzej Kopański",
  "url": "https://github.com/xidedix"
 }
],
"homepage": "https://coreui.io/angular",
"copyright": "Copyright 2018 creativeLabs Łukasz Holeczek",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build --prod",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
"@angular/common": "6.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "6.0.2",
"@angular/core": "6.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "6.0.2",
"@angular/http": "6.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.2",
"@angular/router": "6.0.2",
"@coreui/angular": "^2.13.1",
"@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
"@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
"@coreui/icons": "^0.1.1",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.2",
"@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^2.0.0",
"@ngx-loading-bar/http": "^2.0.0",
"@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "^2.0.0",
"@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^2.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
"@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
"ag-grid-angular": "^23.0.3",
"ag-grid-community": "^23.2.1",
"angular-gtag": "^1.0.3",
"angular-highcharts": "^10.0.1",
"angular-material-fileupload": "0.0.11",
"angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
"angular2-spinner": "^1.0.10",
"bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
"chart.js": "2.7.2",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.4.0",
"core-js": "2.5.6",
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
"file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"flag-icon-css": "3.0.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"highcharts": "^6.2.0",
"moment": "^2.29.3",
"mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.2",
"ng-image-slider": "^1.3.7",
"ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.5",
"ngx-custom-validators": "^8.0.0",
"ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "6.0.0",
"ngx-select-dropdown": "^0.4.1",
"ngx-toastr": "^8.7.3",
"rxjs": "6.1.0",
"rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
"simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
"xlsx": "^0.15.3",
"zone.js": "0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.6.8",
"@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.2",
"@angular/language-service": "6.0.2",
"@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.47",
"@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
"@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
"@types/node": "10.1.0",
"codelyzer": "4.3.0",
"jasmine-core": "3.1.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
"karma": "2.0.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.4.2",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.1.0",
"protractor": "5.3.2",
"ts-node": "6.0.3",
"tslint": "5.10.0",
"typescript": "2.7.2"
},
"engines": {
"node": ">= 8.9.4",
"npm": ">= 5.6.0"
}
}
```

Project will be updated after deploying new changes, is there any way I can install new packages without breaking my node modules?
Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors? It would also be useful if you tried to remove all the other third party packages you have installed to make sure the culprit isn't elsewhere.

Comment: @Cuzy The errors are of coreui components, in order to use them I need to upgrade my project which is not priority as of now.

Comment: What are the error messages? If it's about peer dependencies then you likely have to use an older version of the package that's still compatible with Angular 6. If there is no such version, then you cannot use the package in your project without upgrading your Angular version.

Comment: @Cuzy I have submitted this issue on github as well where I came to know the version I'm using is currently being used by v13. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882897/error-in-node-modules-coreui-angular-lib-sidebar-app-sidebar-service-d-ts7-20

Answer (score 0):

Your version miss match issues.
`npm install packgageName@compatibleVersionName`

e.g
i am using angular 12 i want to install swiperjs. so i simple type this
`npm install swiper@6`

and your using angular 6

Comment: The package that I'm installing is supported to v6.

Comment: So It means your node version issue because bcryptjs is a backend third-party libs

Comment: Please Share the Error Screen